# Connect to Databricks through ODBC without downloading driver

Tags: c#, .net, odbc, azure-databricks, databricks-connect

I need to connect to Databricks in order to run queries from my .NET app. I'd like to avoid the `Rest API` approach and use ODBC but I saw that, in order for the ODBC approach to work, I'd need to download an ODBC driver (Simba Spark). So, can I connect with Databricks through ODBC without any ODBC driver?

I need this because when it comes time for a deploy on my web app, I saw that these kind of drivers cannot be deployed on Azure so basically I can make this work only locally. But that's not my goal, the goal is to deploy it and put it in a production, providing service for different conditions and different queries.

Comment: can you please share exact name of odbc name and link . I can try from my end and update you . @anthino12

Comment: Hey, sure! This is the link from the official Databricks' website: https://databricks.com/spark/odbc-drivers-download